# What is the search function called when i press the windows key on my laptop?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I'm on Ubuntu 21.10, and I'm just wondering, when I press the Windows key on my laptop, it brings up a search window where I can search my entire computer. Does this search have a name? What do we call it?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's called the "Activities overview" (https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-introduction.html#activities). This includes the Exposé-style window grid, the workspace switcher, and the system search.